# How is the MarkLogic error handler triggered when $error:errors is empty?

Tags: marklogic

I have a MarkLogic HTTP server running, with a custom error handler.

On one specific URL I'm trying to hit, I'm getting routed to the error handler.  Not all the pages route to the error handler, so the rest of the site is working.

But, here is what is confusing to me: I know for a fact that I'm hitting the error handler specified (due to logging), but the external variable `$error:errors` is an empty sequence.

Here is what online documentation says:

> The XQuery module can get the HTTP error code and the contents of the HTTP response using the xdmp:get-response-code API. The XQuery module for the error handler also has access to the XQuery stack trace, if there is one; the XQuery stack trace is passed to the module as an external variable with the name $error:errors

So it admits that it is possible to not have a stack trace.

My question is - if there is no stack trace, there was no error(?).  If there was no error, why am I getting routed to the error handler?  How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2):

404 "Page Not Found" errors are sent to the custom error handler.  Because it is not a code error, and therefore there is no error stack, then that could be a scenario in which you'd be sent to the error handler without a stack trace.

I found this out by realizing that my rewriter was sending me to a file that did not exist.  No code or syntax errors in that, but it's still an error.